Cannot find who changed file name
In a document library I found a document that changed the name to something not related to the content.
In the image attached you see 2 file name changes but till today, it had a 3rd filename not listed there.
I cannot understand who changed the file name, and why there is no information in the versioning.
Is possible that the file (a pptx) has been opened via client and modified? (but again why isn't there any entry in the versioning? and it seems quite strange to me, since the file size is always the same)


Here are two methods to check.
1.In the modern experience, select the file -> Details -> Activities.
2.Check through audit logs.
(1)Sign into the Microsoft Purview portal.
(2)Select the Audit solution card.
(3)On the Search page, configure the following search criteria as applicable as following.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-search?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=microsoft-purview-portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/audit-log-activities?view=o365-worldwide
